# SharePoint column formatting referring to Hyperlink Column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In my list, I am referring to a hyperlink column on whether or not to show a field in a different column.  My hyperlink field name is "Link to Site", so the internal name is "Link_x0020_to_x0020_Site".

I cannot get the logic to show/hide appropriately based on whether the Url in the hyperlink is empty or not - here is the beginning of my json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https: //developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "span",
  "style": {
    "color": "#0078d7",
    "display": "=if([$Link_x0020_to_x0020_Site]=='', '', 'none'"
  },
```

Comment: Hi @Chris, did you try my solution given below, is it working for you? Let me know if you still need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the `span` element if hyperlink column is empty, use in this format:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "span",
  "style": {
    "color": "#0078d7",
    "display": "=if([$Link_x0020_to_x0020_Site] == '', 'inherit', 'none')"
  },
```

If you want to hide the `span` element if hyperlink column is empty, use in this format:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "span",
  "style": {
    "color": "#0078d7",
    "display": "=if([$Link_x0020_to_x0020_Site] == '', 'none', 'inherit')"
  },
```

You can also try using `block` if `inherit` is not working for you.